# How to prevent vim from highlighting random words and types

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I've been trying to disable vim from highlighting random words and types for a few hours now. I've noticed vim will highlight specific types when I write python and golang programmes. Even my `.vimrc` file has random highlighting. I've tried setting `set nospell` in my `.vimrc` and have experimented with a number of themes but can't seem to solve this problem, even after researching about it online for a few hours. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:
[image]
Here's my `.vimrc` file

```
syntax enable
set number relativenumber
set ts=4
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set showmatch
let python_hightlight_all=1
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()


au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix

set encoding=utf-8

au BufRead *.py set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4


set incsearch

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'dracula/vim'
Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plugin 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'hashivim/vim-terraform'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'fatih/vim-go'
call vundle#end()
color dracula
set laststatus=2
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
set cursorline
set nospell
autocmd! FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
autocmd FileType go nmap <buffer> <F5>  <Plug>(go-build)
autocmd FileType go nmap <buffer> <F6>  <Plug>(go-run)
```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the maintainers of the dracula theme, I believe what you are seeing is dracula’s italics (which fallback to this highlighting in terminals not supporting italics).

As noted in `:help dracula`, you can turn this off by doing

```
let g:dracula_italic = 0
```

before you load dracula.

Comment: Also note that recent versions of dracula need to be loaded in a slightly different way depending on your plugin manager. Check the github out for information.